# error while submitting data in the form django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to insert data into db it throws below error,can any please fix this.

```
enter code here

model.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
     assign = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     doj = models.DateField()

     class Meta:
        db_table= 'profile'


     def __unicode__(self):

       return  u'%s' % (self.name)



class working(models.Model):
   w_name =models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_column='w_name')
   monday =  models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='monday', blank=True)
   tuesday =  models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='tuesday', blank=True)
   wednesday =  models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='wednesday', blank=True)

   class Meta:
        db_table = 'working'



   def __unicode__(self):
      return  u'%s ' % ( self.w_name)

forms.py

from models import *
from django import forms

class WorkingForm(forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['w_name'] =forms.CharField(initial='x',widget=forms.HiddenInput())

  class Meta:
        model = working
        exclude = ('id')

view.py

# Create your views here.
from forms import *
from django import http
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404


def index(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
          form = WorkingForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return http.HttpResponse('Added')
  else:  
    form = WorkingForm()
  return render_to_response('add_workingdays.html',locals())

Error Message:

ValueError at /

Cannot assign "u'x'": "working.w_name" must be a "Profile" instance.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.2.4
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

Cannot assign "u'x'": "working.w_name" must be a "Profile" instance.

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.2.4
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'check']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/xyz/newapp/../newapp/check/views.py" in index
  10.           if form.is_valid():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  121.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  269.         self._post_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  320.         self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/forms/models.py" in construct_instance
  51.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in save_form_data
  416.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __set__
  318.                                  self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: Cannot assign "u'x'": "working.w_name" must be a "Profile" instance.
```

I did a foreign key relation between two tables and i am trying to insert the data to working table it get Cannot assign "u'x'": "working.w_name" must be a "Profile" instance.

If I remove

```
def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
    super(WorkingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['w_name'] =forms.CharField(initial='x',widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

it works normally,but i want to enter the username as hidden,but it throwing foreign key error

**EDIT:**

Also refer to [Foriegnkey issue while submitting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941206/foriegnkey-issue-while-submitting-the-form/4941223) for a problem throwing same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
Looks like normally for `ForeignKey` fields the `ModelForm` generates a `ModelChoiceField` where its `to_python` method manages getting the foreign key instance from a PK value.

`CharField.to_python` just returns `smart_unicode(value)`

I would override the `ModelForm` `clean_w_name` method and ensure it returns a Profile object from your key.

```
class WorkingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['w_name'] =forms.CharField(initial='x',widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_w_name(self):

        data = self.cleaned_data['w_name']
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=data)
            return profile
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Profile doesn't exist")

    class Meta:
        model = working
        exclude = ('id')
```

Comment: here name is PK name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True),it saves the name in the w_name working table.

Comment: Hmm, good call. Don't know how to help there, but this sounds interesting! I'm going to go dig into it

Comment: Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: Cannot assign "u'x'": "working.w_name" must be a "Profile" instance.

Comment: No prob :) I keep getting to dig into django too. Looks like normally the `ModelChoiceField.to_python` takes care of this conversion but `CharField.to_python` just returns `smart_unicode(value)`

Comment: I have doudt here ,how to check clean in below example      obj=working()
     obj.at_ldap = 'x'
     obj.Monday=  1
     obj.Tuesday = 1
     obj.Wednesday=1
     obj.save()

Comment: Hm, what do you mean? Where is that code you pasted? form.save()? (might be better as a new question)

Comment: for the same model if i want to save the data to the model in the view.py, obj=working()[its the working model]in the view i write method def add_work(request): obj=working()  obj.w_name='x' obj.Monday=1 obj.Tuesday=1  obj.Wednesday=1 obj.save()

Comment: I'm confused. The point of the modelform is the save() method which auto updates the model. If you're setting object attributes directly in the view and want to get access to the cleaned_data, you'd just get it from form.cleaned_data['w_name'] or whatever (note: this data is only available on `is_valid()`)

Comment: sorry,instead of pulling data from the form,i want to directly insert the values using object attribute in views.py.

Comment: Oh, you want to insert data into the form?

Comment: I would personally do a mutablepost = request.POST.copy() then mutablepost.update({'new_fields': 'new_values'}) then pass in mutablepost to the form constructor if you want to inject new values

Comment: seriously though, you should make a new question if you want new specific answers! Comments are not an ideal place to communicate, I don't even know if the mutablepost is the best way :P

Comment: I have created a new question ,here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941206/foriegnkey-issue-while-submitting-the-form